# Algorithm verification: Get all the combinaison of possible word

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, combinations, verification

I wanted to know if the algorithm that i wrotte just below in python is correct.

My goal is to find an algorithm that print/find all the possible combinaison of words that can be done using the character from character '!' (decimal value = 33) to character '~' (decimal value = 126) in the asccii table:

[image: ascii table]

Here the code using recursion:

```
byteWord = bytearray(b'\x20')  # Hex = '\x21' & Dec = '33' & Char = '!'

cntVerif = 0  # Test-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt: int):
    global cntVerif  # Test------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if len(bytes_arr) > 3:  # Test-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        print(f'{cntVerif+1}:TEST END')
        sys.exit()

    if bytes_arr[cnt] == 126:
        if cnt == len(bytes_arr) or len(bytes_arr) == 1:
            bytes_arr.insert(0, 32)
        bytes_arr[cnt] = 32
        cnt += 1
        cntVerif += 1  # Test----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        print(f'{cntVerif}:if bytes_arr[cnt] == 126: \n\tbytes_arr = {bytes_arr}')  # Test-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt)

    if cnt == -1 or cnt == len(bytes_arr)-1:
        bytes_arr[cnt] = bytes_arr[cnt] + 1
        cntVerif += 1  # Test----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        print(f'{cntVerif}:if cnt==-1: \n\tbytes_arr = {bytes_arr}')  # Test-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt=-1)  # index = -1 means last index

    bytes_arr[cnt] = bytes_arr[cnt] + 1
    cntVerif += 1  # Test--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    print(f'{cntVerif}:None if: \n\tbytes_arr={bytes_arr}')  # Test-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    comb_fct(bytes_arr, cnt+1)


comb_fct(byteWord, -1)
```

Thank your for your help because python allow just a limited number of recursion (996 on my computer) so i for exemple i can't verify if my algorithm give all the word of length 3 that can be realised with the range of character describe upper.

Of course if anyone has a better idea to writte this algorithm (a faster algorithm for exemple). I will be happy to read it.

Comment: Avoid recursion. Prefer iterators. Fortunately this is already done in itertools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you might be able to tweak this a bit, I think the code below is close to the most efficient solution to your problem, which I take to be "generate all possible sequences of maximum length *N* from a given set of characters". That might be a bit more general than you need, since your set of characters is fixed, but the general solution is more useful and little overhead is added.

Note that the function is written as a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators), using functions from the [`itertools` standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). Itertools is described as a set of "functions creating iterators for **efficient** looping" (emphasis added), and it indeed is. Generators are one of Python's great features, since they allow you to easily and efficiently iterate over complex sequences. If you want to write efficient and "pythonic" code, you should familiarise yourself with these concepts (as well as other essential features, such as [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)). So I'm not going to explain these features further; please read the tutorial sections for details.

So here's the simple solution:

```py
from itertools import product, chain

def genseq(maxlen, chars):
    return map(''.join,
               chain.from_iterable(product(chars, repeat=i)
                                   for i in range(maxlen+1)))

# Example usage:
chars = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(33, 127))
for word in genseq(4, chars):
    # Do something with word
```

There are 78,914,411 possible words (including the empty word); the above generates all of them in 7 seconds on my laptop. Much of that time is spent creating (and garbage collecting) those strings; you might well be able to do better using a `bytearray` and recycling it for each generated word. I didn't try that.

For the record, here's a simpler way of "unindexing" an enumeration of such strings. The enumeration starts with the empty word, followed by all 1-character words, then 2-character words, and so on. This ordering makes it unnecessary to specify the length (or even maximum length) of the resulting string.

```py
def unindex(i, chars):
    v = []
    n = len(chars)
    while i > 0:
        i -= 1
        v.append(i % n)
        i //= n
    return ''.join(chars[j] for j in v[::-1])

# Example to generate the same words as above:
# chars as above
index_limit = (len(chars) ** 5 - 1) // (len(chars) - 1)
for i in range(0, index_limit):
    word = unindex(i, chars)
    # Do something with word
```

Again, you can probably speed this up a bit by using a recycled bytearray. As written above, it took about two minutes, sixteen times as long as my first version.

Note that using bytearrays in the way you do in your answer does not significantly speed things up, because it creates a new bytearray each time. In order to achieve the savings, you have to use a single bytearray for the entire generations, modifying it rather than recreating it. That's more awkward in practice, because it means that if you need to keep a generated word around for later, perhaps because it passed some test, you must copy it.  It's easy to forget that, and the resulting bug can be very hard to track down.

Comment: Thank a lot, indeed i was looking for the fastest solution and a solution of my own (an algorithm that i ve coded).

Comment: @X0-user-0X: Fair enough. It might be interesting for you to figure out how my unindex function works, since it is so similar to the way you'd unindex a sequence of fixed length (the main difference is subtracting one each time through the loop).

Comment: Just to be sure the line of code: $ chars = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)) $ do the same thing as this line of code in my previous code yes? $ asciiList = []
for c in (chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)):
    asciiList.append(c) $ ? I know this sound stupid but i can't right now run my code

Comment: It's the same thing, except that it creates a string instead of a list of characters. The list of characters would be `[chr(i) for i in range(33,127)]`, which is essentially the same as your loop but less wordy and faster.

Comment: Really great, it seems that you ve optimized very far the code again a big thank.

Comment: Last question i swear. Your code is indeed excellent. But just to be sure, if i want to check only all the combinaison of word from `length_i` to `length_j'; i just have to edit your `genseq` function as follow: `def genseq(maxlen, chars):
    return map(''.join,
               chain.from_iterable(product(chars, repeat=i)
                                   for i in range(length_i, length_j+1)))` Is this correct?

Comment: Personally, I'd put those variables in the function prototype, perhaps as `def genseq(minlen, maxlen, chars)`. (Or some other order, up to you. But yeah, that's the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a recursion here. Consider your word as a `n`-digit number, where the digits are ASCII symbols in the range of interest (`[!..~]`). Start with the smallest one (all `!`), and increment it by 1, until you reach the largest (all `~`).

To increment the long number, add 1 to the least significant byte. If it becomes `~`, make it `!` and try to increment the next one, etc.

Keep in mind that the amount of words is huge. There are `94 ** n` n-letter words. For `n == 4` there are 78074896 of them.

Comment: In Python, you can use `itertools.product`, which doesn't require you to store all the results.

Comment: @rici thank you, have an exemple?

Comment: @user58697 It's exactlly what i am trying to do. But how do you this? have you a code exemple?

Comment: @X0-user-0X: There are examples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product), which you can also read from a Python session by typing `import itertools` and then `help(itertools.product)`. It's usually used in a `for` loop: `for p in itertools.product('ABCDEFG', repeat=3): ...`. You can easily create a list (or whatever), but it's not a particularly good idea; as user58697 points out, the number of possibilities is well beyond your memory capacity.

Comment: @rici Thank you btw i think i found a better way to do it

Comment: @user58697 i ve just posted an answer using base conversion (from base 10 to base 94). I think it is a more elegant answer and that it is too optimal in time and space. Can you please tell me it is correct?

Comment: @rici  i ve just posted an answer using base conversion (from base 10 to base 94). I think it is a more elegant answer and that it is too optimal in time and space. Can you please tell me it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

**EXPLANATION:**

To solve this problem i think that i ve found a more elegant and faster way to do it without using recursive algorithm.
*Complexity:*
I think too that it is the time and space optimal solution.
As it is in time: O(n) with n the total number of possible combinaison that can be **very very** high. And theorically O(1) in space complexity. Concerning  the space complexity because of the python language characteristics my code ,from a practical point of view, creates a lot of bytearray. This can be corrected with light modification. But for a better code check the solution posted by [@ricci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) that i marked as the accepted answer.
*Mathematical principle used:*
I am using the fact that it exists a bijection between all the number in decimal basis and the number in base 94.
It is obvious that each number in base 94 can be written using a special sequance of unique character as the one in the range [30, 126] (in decimal value) in the ascii code.
*Exemple of base conversion:*
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html
The operator '//' is the quotient operator and the operator '%' is the modulo operator.

I will be happy if anyone can confirm that my solution is correct. :-)

**ALGORITHM**

*VERSION 1:*
If you are NOT interested by getting all the sequence of words starting by '!'.
For exemple in lenght 2, you are NOT interested by the words of the form `'!!'...'!A' '!B' ... etc ...'!R'...'!~'` (as in our base '!' is equivalent to zero).

```
# Get all ascii relevant character in a list
asciiList = []
for c in (chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)):
    asciiList.append(c)
print(f'ascii List: \n{asciiList} \nlist length: {len(asciiList)}')


def base10_to_base94_fct(int_to_convert: int) -> str:
    sol_str = ''
    loop_condition = True

    while loop_condition is True:
        quo = int_to_convert // 94
        mod = int_to_convert % 94
        sol_str = asciiList[mod] + sol_str
        int_to_convert = quo
        if quo == 0:
            loop_condition = False

    return sol_str


# test = base10_to_base94_fct(94**2-1)
# print(f'TEST result: {test}')


def comb_fct(word_length: int) -> None:
    max_iter = 94**word_length

    cnt = 1
    while cnt < max_iter:
        str_tmp = base10_to_base94_fct(cnt)
        cnt += 1
        print(f'{cnt}: Current word check:{str_tmp}')


# Test
comb_fct(3)
```

*VERSION 2:*
If you are interested by getting all the sequence of words starting by '!'.
For exemple in lenght 2, you are interested by the words of the form  `'!!'...'!A' '!B' ... etc ...'!R'...'!~'` (as in our base '!' is equivalent to zero).

```
# Get all ascii relevant character in a list
asciiList = []
for c in (chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)):
    asciiList.append(c)
print(f'The word should contain only the character in the following ascii List: \n{asciiList} \nlist length: {len(asciiList)}')


def base10_to_base94_fct(int_to_convert: int, str_length: int) -> bytearray:
    sol_str = bytearray(b'\x21') * str_length
    digit_nbr = str_length-1
    loop_condition = True

    while loop_condition is True:
        quo = int_to_convert // 94
        mod = int_to_convert % 94
        sol_str[digit_nbr] = 33 + mod
        digit_nbr -= 1
        int_to_convert = quo
        if digit_nbr == -1:
            loop_condition = False

    return sol_str


def comb_fct(max_word_length: int) -> None:
    max_iter_abs = (94/93) * (94**max_word_length-1)  # sum of a geometric series: 94 + 94^2 + 94^3 + 94^4 + ... + 94^N
    max_iter_rel = 94
    word_length = 1

    cnt_rel = 0  # rel = relative
    cnt_abs = 0  # abs = absolute
    while cnt_rel < max_iter_rel**word_length and cnt_abs < max_iter_abs:
        str_tmp = base10_to_base94_fct(cnt_rel, word_length)
        print(f'{cnt_abs}:Current word test:{str_tmp}.')
        print(f'cnt_rel = {cnt_rel} and cnt_abs={cnt_abs}')
        if str_tmp == bytearray(b'\x7e') * word_length:
            word_length += 1
            cnt_rel = 0
            continue
        cnt_rel += 1
        cnt_abs += 1

comb_fct(2)  # Test
```

Comment: This is not correct. Your loop ends when the quotient is 0, which means that it will stop prematurely for numbers corresponding to strings starting with `!` (other than the string `!` itself). If you intend to find all strings of length no greater than 3 (of which there are 94**3 + 94**2 + 94, not counting the empty string), you'll need a slightly more sophisticated encoding. If you want all strings of length 3, you need to run the loop exactly 3 times.

Comment: Anyway, the generator `(''.join(p) for p in product((chr(i) for i in range(33,127)), repeat=3))` is more than twice as fast. (And a lot less typing.)

Comment: @rici 1/So you say that there is an error in my conversion function? 2-The line of code in your second commentary referred to wich part?

Comment: @rici why and where therre is an error in my conversion function from base 10 to base 94?    
Actually according to what i understood the conversion stop when the quotient is equal to zero aka the previous quotient we get in the loop where smaller than 94.

Comment: Generate all two-character strings and then let me know if `!R` appears in the list.

Comment: The line of code produces all 3-character strings. Change the 3 in repeat=3 if you want a different length.

Comment: @rici
You re right it doesn't appear, i understand where is the erroe. I ll try to correct it

Comment: @rici and what if i want to use each of those word?

Comment: `for word in (''.join(p) for p in product(asciiList, repeat=3)): # do something with word`

Comment: @rici
Thk you you re a champ all yout comment are very very good :-) Now i ve to go but i will return to this code soon and i ll try to correct the problem you told me (hte fact that the word begining by '!' will not appear). i have an idea on how to do it. Thnk

Comment: @rici Hi rici. I just edited my answer (code version2) to solve the difficulty that you ve identified. I will be happy if you can tell me now if is it correct? (that means for exemple all the words of length 2 beguining by '!' will appear). Btw i am indeed looking for the fastest method to get alll the combinaisons of words of length 'n' in the range of character. So can you explain me why the line of code you gave me will be faster?

Comment: @rici And please can you confirm me that the maximum number of combinaison in the cas of a word of length N is: 94+94^2+94^3+...+94^N ? Thk

Comment: Yes, that's correct for the count of words of maximum length N, although normally we'd add 1 for the empty string. With that minor change, the count can also be written as `(94**(N+1)-1)/93`.

Comment: My line is much faster because the bulk of the work is done inside a carefully-optimized standard library function written in C. Familiarity with the standard library is essential if you want to write good code, but so is familiarity with basic Python. Your `while` loop, for example, would be much clearer and more efficient as `for digit_nbr in range(str_length-1,-1,-1)` (in the second program), and comprehensions are almost always better than loops for constructing lists.

Comment: Thank for all your help, now i would mark this answer correct asap